# Controlling a QObject working in another thread, bypassing event queue, freezes the GUI

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qthread

I'm working with `QThread` and slots/signals mechanism; I know there's a **lot** of threads about this on the Web in general and here at SO in particular, but I still could not find a solution. Anyway, here is the context.

The piece of code I am trying to come up with is aimed at controlling though the GUI an eventually long process, hence the use of a `QThread`.

I have a window with two buttons, start and stop. My `Window` also has a `QThread` and `Task`, where the latter inherits from a `QObject`. I do want to be able to stop my task while it is running, and to prevent starting it again if start is clicked while it is already running.

Here is an excerpt of `Task` (which fakes the long process):

```
class Task: public QObject
{
public:

  Task(): QObject(), stop_(true) {}

private slots:

  void startTask()
  {
    stop_ = false;
    run();
  }

  void stopTask()
  {
    stop_ = true;
  }

  void run() const
  {
    while ( ! stop_)
    {
      sleep(1);
    }
  }

  bool stop_;
};
```

I made two connections between the buttons and the task in the constructor of my `Window`:

```
class Window: public QWidget
{
public:

  Window()
  {
    // Instantiate buttons and put them in a layout.
    // ...

    connect(buttonStart_, SIGNAL(clicked()), &task_, SLOT(startTask()));
    connect(buttonStop_, SIGNAL(clicked()), &task_, SLOT(stopTask()),
            Qt::DirectConnection);

    task_.moveToThread(&thread);
    thread_.start();
  }

private:
  QPushButton buttonStart_;
  QPushButton buttonStop_;

  QThread thread_;
  Task task_;
};
```

I used `Qt::DirectConnection` in the second `connect()` in order to "force" processing of my signal requesting to stop the task, as (as I understand) `task_` needs to return from its work before processing events further (if I use the default connection, all my clicks are processed after my task is "done").

Here, the `Qt::DirectConnection` "bypasses" the event queue, and that way I can stop my task. But to be honest I don't know if that is the proper way to do it, or if it is a workaround (thus possibly the root of my problem).

Anyway, this works OK that way, but when I start playing with my buttons, the GUI gets eventually frozen, and that's my problem!

Any help is welcome; thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `DirectConnection` means that the slots will be executed in the UI thread (while your task thread is still running).  This is not what you want.  The way to handle this is to use an event loop in your thread, by running with `QThread::exec()`.

In order for your thread to be able to respond as you want, you will need to ensure that the thread is able to process incoming events.  There are a few ways to deal with this.  One would be to call `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` occasionally while your task is running.  Another is to use a `QTimer` connected to a slot which performs some processing.  The important thing is to make sure that the event loop in your thread can run.

Comment: Do you mean that my `Task::run()` method prevents my thread from processing anything, even signals? What I understand from your answer is that my `while` loop should call `processEvents()` (or similar) on a regular basis. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, if your task is running inside the thread, the thread is not able to do anything else unless you tell it to.  Calling `processEvents()` in your while loop should work (as long as the thread has been started with exec()).  ETA: Something I just noticed, the default QThread::run() already calls exec(), so that part will work.  Just get rid of the DirectConnection and call processEvents() in your task's run() loop.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to understand is which thread your signal/slot connections are being executed in.

The default behavior in this particular case is to use a `Qt::QueuedConnection`, which will put your signal event onto the receiving thread's event queue.  In the case of a `Qt::DirectConnection`, the slot is executed **in the thread of the object that emitted the signal**.

Using a Qt::DirectConnection would only be safe in this instance if you put a mutex around your stop_ variable to prevent both threads from accessing it at the same time.

Comment: Actually, I tried putting a mutex around my `stop_` variable, but it did not solve the problem (what I did: `Task` gets a `QMutex` member and `stop_` manipulation are surrounded with calls to `lock()` and `unlock()`). But using `Qt::QueuedConnection` will make the receiving thread (the one dedicated to my task) process my event only after my task is finished. I want to process it while it is working.